# How to pass parameter to invoke method as a vararg of a relfected class in case of Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

I have a project in which I am using a third party library. However, I need to call methods from the third party only if the user has copied those jars in the project, or else use the existing jars. **For this purpose I am using reflection for creating the classes and calling the methods from this third party library**.

One of the methods from the library expects varargs of another class from the same library as argument. Since both the classes have been created in my main class using reflection and also their corresponding methods have been created using reflection, how do we pass argument as vararg of a class to the methodname.**invoke()** method?

Refer the code snippet ahead.

//-------Class A-----------------

```
package com.demoA;

Class A {
   public void methodA(B... b) {
      // Contents of methodA...
   }
}
```

//-------Class B-----------------

```
package com.demoB;

Class B {
    // contents of class B here...
}
```

//-------Class MainClass-------------

```
package com.mainclass;

Class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> azz = Class.forName("com.demoA.A");
        Object aObject = azz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        Method methodAReflected = null;
    
        for (Method m : azz.getMethods) {
            if (m.getName.equals("methodA")) {
                methodAReflected = m;
            }
        }
        
          Class bzz = Class.forName("com.demoB.B");
          Object bObject = bzz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        
          methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, <how to pass varargs here>);
          // Passing only bObject or new Object[] { bObject } result in an IllegalArgumentException : type mismatch
    
    }
}
```

Also, is there is any better way (rather than iterating through the method names) to use Java reflection's **getMethod()** method to create the reflected method when the expected parameter is a vararg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,int)) to create a new array, and use [`Array.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#set(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object)) to set its elements.

```
Object methodAVarargs = Array.newInstance(bzz, 1);
Array.set(methodAVarargs, 0, bObject);
methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, methodAVarargs);
```

To find the method with a shorter code, you can use `get(Declared)Method` and pass the [`arrayType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType()) of `bzz`:

```
Method methodAReflected = azz.getDeclaredMethod("methodA", bzz.arrayType());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked as expected.

The only problem in using the shorter code for getMethod() is that I am using Java 11 and the method arrayType() has been introduced since Java 12, so cannot use this method.

Comment: @AbhishekIngale In that case I think you can also get it with `Class.forName("[Lcom.demoB.B")` - i.e. adding a `[L` prefix to the class name.

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, just one correction, we need to add a semicolon at the end of class name while using Class.forName in the case of creating a class of array type.
So the line of code would be:
Method m = azz.getMethod("methodA", Class.forName("[Lcom.demoB.B;"));

Comment: Well, when you create the array beforehand, using the method shown in this answer, you can also use `methodAVarargs.getClass()`, to get the `Class` object representing the array type.

Comment: Since we know `bzz` is always a class (and not a primitive), we can have `methodAVarargs` be of type `Object[]`, and just set elements with `methodAVarargs[0] = bObject;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call it with approach like this:

```
B[] bObjectArray = <array of Bs>;
methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, (Object) bObjectArray);
```

Also you can check official [tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html), where in section *Invoking Methods with a Variable Number of Arguments* you can find example of using something similar that you need.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I added some debug code to see the real invocations:

```java
// add identificator to the class
class B {
    private final String id;

    public B(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

// print args on invocation
class A {
    public void methodA(B... b) {
        var s = Arrays.stream(b).map(B::getId).reduce("", (acc, x) -> acc + x + ",");
        System.out.println("params (" + b.length + "): " + s);
    }
}
```

And final code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bObject1 = (B) bzz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("b0");
        B bObject2 = (B) bzz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("b1");

        System.out.println("invoking with no args");
        methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, (Object) new B[]{});

        System.out.println("invoking with bObject1");
        methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, (Object) new B[]{bObject1});

        System.out.println("invoking with bObject1 and bObject2");
        methodAReflected.invoke(aObject, (Object) new B[]{bObject1, bObject2});
}
```

Output:

```
invoking with no args
params (0): 
invoking with bObject1
params (1): b0,
invoking with bObject1 and bObject2
params (2): b0,b1,
```

Quite simple. All we need to remember is that we pass the args as raw `Object`.

Why so?
Firstly, the method *always* takes one parameter:

`methodAReflected.getParameterCount() -> 1`

So let's see the parameter:

```
methodAReflected.getParameters() -> com.example.springsandbox.vararg.B... b
methodAReflected.getParameters()[0].executable -> public void com.example.springsandbox.vararg.A.methodA(com.example.springsandbox.vararg.B[])
```